# Curl in C - don't print html code

Tags: c, curl

I'm using Curl in C, but I don't want to echo the webpage code:

```
CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com");

curl_easy_perform(curl);    
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Is there any Curl option for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution for this problem:

```
size_t function(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}
```

...

```
FILE *outfile;
outfile = fopen("test", "w");

CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.example.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, outfile);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function);

curl_easy_perform(curl);    
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

You can print the html code in in a file and don't print it in the "console"